# Having troubles targeting an h1 inside a div

Tags: html, css

I have this part on my index.html page

```
        <!-- Top of the Page -->
<div id="home" class="container header">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="image-header margin-0">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
            <div class="headertext">
                <h1>EXAMPLE</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to target the word 'EXAMPLE' in my main.css, but I am having troubles with it. Whatever I try, it seems to target the parent divs or not target it at all.

I have tried targeting: 
.headertext .h1
.headertext h1
p h1

I basically tried every combination, but I can't achieve the effect I desire.

My goal is to have an image, then a black overlay with opacity on top of the image and then some text in the center of the page.

Thanks everyone!

edit: removed p tags around h1

edit2: I actually figured it out. There was margin-top added automatically to the h1. I am guessing it's a default in bootstrap? I set margin-top to 0 and it's working fine now. Thanks!

Comment: First I would suggest to avoid using <h> tags inside <p> tags.

Comment: First of all, that is invalid HTML. Remove the containing `<p>` please.

Comment: Secondary, after removing the containing `<p>`, targeting the `<h1>` is done in CSS by simply doing `.headertext h1` or if you want to be very specific, do `#home .row .image-header .headertext h1`

Comment: Sorry about the p tags, I was just trying to get it to work. Targeting .headertext h1 works, but it also has an effect on the parent class image-header (the background image). It pushes it down by about 20 px. As you can see in this screenshot: https://gyazo.com/c92c9d60af7dd95867f5c23ff2b2426b

Comment: If you are having problems with HTML, it is often a good idea to check it with an HTML validator, like the [W3C Markup Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/). Once you have valid markup, then you can ask here.

Comment: The only issues that Validator has is that I am using h1 tags inside a div, I guess?

Consider using the h1 element as a top-level heading only (all h1 elements are treated as top-level headings by many screen readers and other tools).

Such as in this code bit:

<!-- Service Area Section -->
     <section id="area" class="area-section">
         <div class="container">
             <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-lg-12">
                     <h1>Service Area</h1>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </section>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `<h1>` inside of `<p>` as this is an invalid HTML. Although you can use an anchor or a span with a bigger font size.

Please try something like below.

```css
.headertext h1 {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="home" class="container header">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="image-header margin-0">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="headertext">
        <h1>EXAMPLE</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, yes I removed the p tag, rookie mistake. I currently have it setup the way you're showing, but it's also affecting the parent tag of image-header margin-0 which is the background image, it pushes the image down from the top of the page by about 20 px. I have nothing like that in my css anymore

Comment: please add css too,Can't say by seeing only HTML

Comment: Hi, I actually figured it out. There was margin-top added automatically to the h1. I am guessing it's a default in bootstrap? I set margin-top to 0 and it's working fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out. There was margin-top added automatically to the h1. I am guessing it's a default in bootstrap? I set margin-top to 0 and it's working fine now. Thanks!